# Get Location of Page Break

Tags: c#, .net, excel, aspose

I have an Excel with Manual PageBreaks but excel is adding in automatic Pagebreaks also. I need to find the location where the automatic page-break is coming. Could anyone please help me with the code. I have no idea how to proceed either using C# or Aspose.

```
           ImageOrPrintOptions printoption = new ImageOrPrintOptions();
            printoption.PrintingPage = PrintingPageType.Default;
            SheetRender sr = new SheetRender(StateBasis, printoption);
            int pageCount = sr.PageCount;
            // MessageBox.Show(pageCount.ToString());

            CellArea[] area1 = Toc.GetPrintingPageBreaks(printoption);
            //MessageBox.Show(area.Length.ToString());

            for (int m = 0; m < area1.Length;m++)
            {

                //Get the first page rows. 
                int strow = area1[m].StartRow;
                int stcol = area1[m].StartColumn;

                //  MessageBox.Show("Page " + (i + 1).ToString() + " : " + CellsHelper.CellIndexToName(strow, stcol));
                workBook.Worksheets["State Basis"].HorizontalPageBreaks.RemoveAt(strow);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

See the following sample code (using Aspose.Cells APIs) to accomplish your task:
e.g
**Sample code:**

```
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook("e:\\test2\\Book1.xlsx");
    Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

    ImageOrPrintOptions printoption = new ImageOrPrintOptions();
    printoption.PrintingPage = PrintingPageType.Default;
    SheetRender sr = new SheetRender(worksheet, printoption);
    int pageCount = sr.PageCount;
    MessageBox.Show(pageCount.ToString());

    CellArea[] area = worksheet.GetPrintingPageBreaks(printoption);
    MessageBox.Show(area.Length.ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i < area.Length; i++)
    {

        //Get the first page rows. 
        int strow = area[i].StartRow;
        int stcol = area[i].StartColumn;

        MessageBox.Show("Page " + (i + 1).ToString() + " : " + CellsHelper.CellIndexToName(strow, stcol));



    }
```

I am working as Support developer/Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thank you so much, Amjad. Now, if I have to remove the automatic page-break at the specified location all I need to do is workbook.Worksheets[0].HorizontalPageBreaks.RemoveAt(strow);
Also, it will remove the automatic page breaks only and not the manual ones ?

Comment: I get all the pagebreaks even the manual ones but, i only want the automatic ones. Also, it does not give any value in strow and stcol.

Comment: Well, you may try to use Worksheet.HorizontalPageBreaks.RemoveAt() method and  Worksheet.VerticalPageBreaks.RemoveAt() method to remove horizontal and vertical pages breaks based on its index (0-based, e.g 0 --> first page break, 1 --> second page break, 2 --> third page break). Also, all page breaks would be retrieved (whether you have added them manually or these are automatic(existing)). Both manual and automatic pages breaks are called printing page breaks and you will get all types of page breaks.

Comment: Hi Amjad, I am not able to get the exact location where the manual page break is added. It gives some row before the page break. Any insights? Also, i am not getting the automatic page break number. Is there anything you can suggest or any other alternative?

Comment: The issue needs to be evaluated on our end first. By the way, you may insert blank rows/columns into the sheet and measure the content width, such as, row height/column width, page count of the worksheet, etc. We appreciate if you could provide us some samples (Excel files) and complete details on your issue and what you need to achieve, etc.